# php global variable is null

Tags: php, function, laravel, global-variables, laravel-4

I have a `protected $headers` variable in my class assigning a value using the function

```
public function actionLogIn()
{
$userCode = Input::get('username');
$password = Input::get('password'); 
$loginData = array(
    'code' => $userCode,
    'passkey' => $password
);
$loginData = json_encode($loginData);   
$this->headers = Auth::login($loginData);//Modified login method
if(! is_null($this->headers))
{
    return View::make('forms.welcome')->with('title', 'Welcome');
}else{
    echo "Invalid access!";
}
}
```

and when I use `print_r($this->headers);` it successfully prints out the value I need, 
but when I tried to access `$this->headers` using the function:

```
public function actionLogOut()
{
    if(is_null($this->headers)){
        echo "is null", "\n";
    }//for checking only
    Auth::logout($this->headers);
}
```

`$this->headers` is null. What could be the problem ? also `$headers` is actually an array. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: `$this->headers` _can_ be null, given the code you show here, if you call `actionLogOut` prior to calling `actionLogIn`... all objects are destroyed when the response is sent to the client

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem but actionLogIn is called out first.
on that note, what could be the best solution for this? on the condition that I do not have to use Sessions

Comment: @shin-shan: in _the same_ request? so the user logs in, and logs out in a single request? why not use sessions?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem oh, sorry, I just edited my comment a while ago

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem well, the point is I want to pass some `$headers` to `actionLogOut`. I've seen how the Auth class of Lavaravel does this in `Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php` if my understanding is correct, I just did the same

Answer (score 0):

A new controller instance is created for every request.  That means that even though you store information in $this, it's not there when the user requests a new page.

What you want to do is store data in something that doesn't change between requests - either in the session or in cookies.

In the session, it would look like this: (warning - untested code)

```
public function actionLogIn() {
  ...
  $loginData = json_encode($loginData);   
  $user = Auth::login($loginData);
  if ($user) {
    Session::put('logged_in_user',$user);
    return View::make('forms.welcome')->with('title', 'Welcome');
  }else{
    echo "Invalid access!";
  }
}

public function actionLogOut() {
  if(Session::has('logged_in_user'){
    $user = Session::get('logged_in_user');
    Auth::logout($user);
    Session::forget('logged_in_user');
  } else {
    echo "is null\n";
  }
}
```

Take a look at http://four.laravel.com/docs/session for more information on Sessions in Laravel.

Comment: Is there no other way but to use sessions?